# Displaying the percentage and absences

Tags: javascript

I've been going at this for a week and can't seem to figure it out..

The program asks for the user to enter the amount of absences they had and their grade, but if the student has 5 or more absences they automatically fail regardless of their percentage.

- Grade A - 90 to 100
- Grade B - 80 to 89.9
- Grade C - 70 to 79.9
- Grade D 60 to 69.9
- Anything below 60 is an F.

Here's my code so far:

```js
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

//Program Name: gradeReporter.html
//Author: 
//Date: November 5th 2015
//Purpose: Calculate grades and absences of students 

//Variables
var percent = parseInt(percent * 1.03);
var absences = parseInt(absences);
var ES = ""; // Empty string
var PA = "<p />"; // HTML paragraph break
var BR = "<br />" // HTML line break 
//Start the program 

if (absences >= 5) {
  document.write("You have failed due to having more than 5 absences");

  if (percent <= 100 || percent >= 90 && absences <=2) {
    document.write("Your Grade: A. Your percent: " * percent);
  } 
  else if (percent <= 89.9 || percent >= 80 && absences <=2) { 
    document.write("Your Grade: B. Your percent: " * percent);
  }
  else if (percent <= 79.9 || percent >= 70 && absences <=2) {
    document.write("Your Grade: C. Your percentage: " * percent);
  }
  else if (percent <= 69.9 || percent >= 60 && absences <=2) {
    document.write("Your Grade: D. Your percentage: " * percent);
  }
  else if (percent <= 59.9 || percent >= 50 && absences <=2) {
    document.write("Grade: F. You have failed this semester.");
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Also, `document.write` is an obsolete technique. Look to DOM insertion (`innerHTML`) instead.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do, the problem seems like a really basic if/else programming exercise, are you trying to replicate the behavior of the question using Javascript/HTML/CSS?

Comment: I need the program to display the user's input.

Comment: Where should `percent` and `absences` originally come from?

Comment: the percentage and absences should come from the user

Comment: In what form? How are you going to capture these values?

Comment: percentage = prompt (maybe)?

Comment: Please see my answer. That code is working.

Comment: Thank you for helping me :).

Answer (score 1):

You need to define first a number for percent and absences. Also when you say "Your percentage" you need to use "+" not "*". Also, some of your brackets were misplaced. This code now should work:

```
//Variables
var percent = 80;
var absences = 6;
percent = percent * 1.03;
var ES = ""; // Empty string
var PA = "<p />"; // HTML paragraph break
var BR = "<br />"   // HTML line break 
//Start the program 

if (absences >= 5) {
document.write("You have failed due to having more than 5 absences");
}
if (percent <= 100 || percent >= 90 && absences <=2) {
document.write("Your Grade: A. Your percent: " + percent);
} 
else if (percent <= 89.9 || percent >= 80 && absences <=2) { 
document.write("Your Grade: B. Your percent: " + percent);
}
else if (percent <= 79.9 || percent >= 70 && absences <=2) {
document.write("Your Grade: C. Your percentage: " + percent);
}
else if (percent <= 69.9 || percent >= 60 && absences <=2) {
document.write("Your Grade: D. Your percentage: " + percent);
}
else if (percent <= 59.9 || percent >= 50 && absences <=2) {
document.write("Grade: F. You have failed this semester.");
}
```

Comment: How about `absences`?

Comment: Yes, you are right! Updated!